# How do I shift one cell in column 2 so that my date is at row 0 while everything other value remains?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: My Dataframe that I am working with]

I am trying to use Pandas.dropna() to the date on column 2 so that the date is at index 0.

`df=pd.read_excel(excel_filepath,sheetname='Consolidated Balance Sheets',header=None)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
df.iloc[0,2] = df.iloc[2,8]
```

Comment: You have the 2 and 8 switched around, but that works. I was trying to figure out a more general way, like if it sees a date in any of the rows, put that date at the top and clear its current spot.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to kind of squeeze just column 2, so the `NaN` values on top disappear (or move down), you can do this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
non_na_values= df['2'].dropna().to_list()
df['2']= np.NaN
df.iloc[:len(non_na_values) , df.columns.get_loc('2')]= non_na_values
```

I know, this is a very unconventional way to do this, but the kind of problem is also very unusual, because normally the column values in a row are related somehow and so in most cases such an operation doesn't make sense. That is probably also the reason, why there is most likely no more elegant solution to solve something like this. I guess you have thought about sorting the data.

Note: Maybe you have to remove the hyphens around the two (depends on what type your column name actually is.